# Campos personalizados wp_customizer

Tags: php, wordpress, cms

Buenas tardes, tengo una plantilla en html5, y lo quiero adecuar con wordpress creando campos personalizados en el customizer, tengo un problema, ya tengo creado el panel principal el cual quiero que aloje las secciones de mi pagina, y a este panel le agregue una sección, pero no he podido agregarle otra, el codigo que tengo es

```
// PANEL PRINCIPAL
    $wp_customize->add_panel( 'davidvpino_theme_options', array(
        'title'       => __( 'Opciones de Tema DavidVPino', 'davidvpino' ),
        'capability'  => 'edit_theme_options',
        'description' => __( 'Administracion de Secciones', 'davidvpino' ),
        'priority'    => 1,
    ) );

    // FIN DE   DEL PANEL PRINCIPAL

    // SECCIONES DEL PANEL PRINCIPAL

    $wp_customize->add_section( 'davidvpino_theme_home', array(
        'title'       => __( 'Seccion Inicio', 'davidvpino' ),
        'capability'  => 'edit_theme_options',
        'panel'             => 'davidvpino_theme_options',
        'description' => __( 'Imagen y texto de la sección Inicio', 'davidvpino' ),
        'priority'    => 10,
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_section( 'davidvpino_theme_about', array(
        'title'       => __( 'Seccion Acerca de', 'davidvpino' ),
        'capability'  => 'edit_theme_options',
        'panel'             => 'davidvpino_theme_options',
        'description' => __( 'Imagen y texto de la sección Acerca de', 'davidvpino' ),
        'priority'    => 20,
    ) );
    // FIN DE SECCIONES DEL PANEL PRINCIPAL
```

la sección `davidvpino_theme_home` me aparece dentro del panel que cree pero `davidvpino_theme_about` no me aparece como se aprecia en la imagen [image: Wp_customize]

Alguien me podría decir exactamente a que se debe, si es que se debe crear otra función tipo array para agregar varias secciones a un panel.

Comment: Buenas, ¿te valió la respuesta?

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero es que te recomiendo usar `Advanced Custom Fields (ACF)`, es un plugin que te resuelve muchísimas horas de desarrollo de Wordpress.

Yo lo uso desde hace mucho tiempo y te facilita enormemente este tipo de cosas.

Si has podido leer el [codex de Wordpress sobre `customize_register`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/customize_register)

Tienes que ejecutar todo dentro del hook `customize_register`, aquí no lo veo pero supongo que estarás dentro de esa función.

Puede que no te esté apareciendo porque no tiene contenido que mostrar, el primero podría aparecer para que no aparezca "vacío".

He probado tu código y funciona, intenta agregarle algo de contenido para ver si tienes algún fallo:

```
$wp_customize->add_section(
    'prueba',
    [
        'title'    => __('Prueba', 'davidvpino'),
        'priority' => 10,
    ]
);

$wp_customize->add_control(
    'slider_display',
    [
        'type'           => 'checkbox',
        'label'          => __('Checkbox prueba.', 'davidvpino'),
        'section'        => 'prueba',
        'priority'       => 10,
    ]
);
```

Si no es así me dices y buscamos posibles errores.

También estaría bien conocer la versión de Wordpress y de PHP. En mi caso `Wordpress 4.8` y `PHP 7.0.18`